# How does GPS work?

Tags: gps, alert

GPS technology is used in safety devices to get the alert in an emergency event. How does GPS work with these devices?

Comment: What are you looking for that's not in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_position-indicating_radiobeacon_station)?  And in what way are you trying to connect one to your general-purpose computer?  Electronic devices are not on-topic for SuperUser, as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Those devices have to have some kind of GPS receiver which might vary in accuracy and a second channel to actually transmit anything.

GPS is a passive system based on a satellite network. Those satellites "broadcast" their time and as the Receiver picks up their signal it's able to use the time difference to get the distance to the satellites. After that some math magic (geometry) is used to get your position. In addition there are some more details involved like the almanac which tells the Receiver where each satellite should be but those are the basics.

The second channel could be a number of things and depends on the actual device. It might be a GSM module, could be internet connected or use some other kind of wireless transmission depending on the circumstances it's supposed to be used in.

Comment: I would imagine the second channel can also be used, as a secondary GPS source, when the primary source is not available..

Comment: Depends on your definition of GPS source. You can e.g. download the Almanac over such a channel to speed up the lock on (transmission from GPS sats is kind of slow) but as you'd need the actual GPS signal and the time difference would be location dependent you're not really using (direct) GPS if you get that information through that secondary channel. A-GPS relies on supplying additional information or in certain circumstances means totally different mechanisms like using GSM radio cells or similar.